# Then I reload page v-if(with computed data) not work

Tags: vue.js, vuex

im search on everywhere information about my questions - not help me.

- I would like to solve this issue using v-if (not v-show)
- I get orders data from Vuex store
- all code work ,then page loaded and mounted and then I click other tabs and going back to    current tab
- code not work then I reload page on current tab
- code work then I reload page on current tab , but without all v-if
- I would like to solve without using third-party plugins if possible

```
<template>
 <div class="w-full">
    <!--show message div-->
    <div v-if="orders.length===0" class="flex flex-wrap">
    ...
    </div>

    <!--show table div-->
    <div v-if="orders.length!==0" class="flex flex-wrap">
    ...
    </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

**computed data**

```
computed: {
  orders() {
      return this.$store.state.dataList.orders
  }
}
```

// in console.log i get 4 my orders objects (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, **ob**: Observer]

**actions:**

```
fetchORDERS ({ commit }) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios.get('/api/data-list/orders')
        .then((response) => {
          commit('SET_ORDERS', response.data)
          resolve(response)
        })
        .catch((error) => { reject(error) })
    })
  }
```

**mutation:**

```
SET_ORDERS (state, order) {
    state. orders = order
}
```

one of the forums they wrote that the matter is in mutation, but I cannot understand what exactly and where is the error, pls help

Comment: show a state defiition

Answer (score 0):

Your basic setup is correct. That v-if should work if the data-flow is correct.

From what you're giving us, I see the following:

In your computed property you're looking at: `this.$store.state.dataList.orders`

In your mutation you're changing `state. orders`. This should be `state.dataList.orders`.

In other words: you should check whether the state has the shape you expect it to have. You can do this with a console.log in the computed property, or one in the mutation.

Comment: dataList is the name of the module,
here is forum link then discus https://forum.vuejs.org/t/then-i-reload-page-v-if-with-computed-data-not-work/106744/7